# common home partition, two systems , 32bit & 64bit

Tags: partitioning, home-directory

question :
is it good for my home partition? common for two systems:
12.04 - 32bit
14.04 - 64bit

I'm going to install this second system 14.04 - 64bit, 
is it possible to work well ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. I'm assuming you want your home folder the same on both partition. They probably won't share it but you can copy(overwrite) your home folder from the 32bit system to the 64 bit system after you've done the installation.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible however, if you were to install programs that use ~/.local or ~/.cache in your home directory will overwrite the folders and files on the other system. Even without installing your own programs/packages KDE and Gnome will store folders in your home directory referencing settings in KDE and Gnome. I, myself wouldn't do it, but happily test it if you like: I'd be interested to see if it worked correctly.

Comment: I've tried that before and it worked